# Finding the general solution to a system with unknown

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field, and $A\in \mathbb{F}^{7\times 7}$ such that $rank(A)=5$ and $b\in \mathbb{F}^7$ such that $b \neq 0$. Given the following three solution vectors to the system $Ax=b$, determine the general solution to this system:
> $$
> X= \begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \\ x_5 \\ 6 \\ 7 \end{bmatrix}
> $$
> $$
> Y= \begin{bmatrix}y_1 \\ y_2 \\ y_3 \\ y_4 \\ y_5 \\ 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}
> $$
> $$
> Z= \begin{bmatrix}z_1 \\ z_2 \\ z_3 \\ z_4 \\ z_5 \\ 4 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}.
> $$

Since $rank(A)=5$, I expect this has something to do with the rank-nullity theorem. Will you help me understand how to tackle this?

Thank you

Comment: HINT: Since $$b=AX=AY=AZ$$ you can show that $$0=A(X-Y)=A(X-Z)$$. Moreover you know (by the rank nullity theorem) that the kernel of $A$ has dimension 2...

Comment: Thank you! It helped!